# Creating a basic spring core application with intellij idea 13 community edition

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am just learning spring and my first program is to load a bean xml and instantiate the classes.

I will be using spring core and I have created a Java project. Created a package called:

> com.lecture

and put the java files there as well as the bean file
spring-beans.xml

```
<beans>
    <bean id="rkdf" class="com.college.RKDFCollege"/>
    <bean id="cseLect" class="com.college.CSELecturer"/>
</beans>
```

But when I am running the main class which has this code:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com.lecture.spring-beans.xml");
```

it is giving me errors

> Dec 07, 2014 9:10:37 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [com.lecture.spring-beans.xml] Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [com.lecture.spring-beans.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [com.lecture.spring-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist

I am new to this I dont have any idea so far! In the project module settings, I have added JDK and Spring jars. Guidance is appreciated.

Comment: A file named `com.lecture.spring-beans.xml` is not there on the classpath. Do you have s file with that name in your filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following path to the XML: `"com/lecture/spring-beans.xml"`

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` treats your class path as a file system.

Comment: And do we have to give the beans xmlns for spring because now SAXParserException is there after the file is found and loaded following your advice.

Comment: Of course. Xml files must have a schema defined in their namesapces.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com.lecture.spring-beans.xml");` is searching `com.lecture.spring-beans.xml` file in the class path which I believe is not the name of the file you have created. I believe you have created file `spring-beans.xml`

Make sure `spring-beans.xml` file is in class path. Else you can put the spring-beans.xml in resource folder as well. Then load the file as:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-beans.xml");
```

Comment: It does not loads, its inside the packge com.lecture, but with Stav Saad's advice, it loaded. But with your comment I get a new doubt, com.lecture is already in classpath and file is inside that package, so why does it not loads with only the xml file name

Comment: Usually, these files are put in resource folder. Once it is in classpath it'll load the file.

Comment: @xploreraj The reason is because the context treats the path relative to the root of the classpath, aka the default package. Each subpackage from there is treated as a folder.

Comment: You cleared the doubt that I was pondering upon. Thanks.